# How to redirect all routes except one in nextjs when using i18n?

Tags: next.js, http-redirect

Note: I have reviewed the similar suggested questions.

I want to redirect ALL app routes (localized via **next's i18n config**) including nested routes

- from: `/route/sub-path/sub-sub-path`
- to `/route/sub-path/sub-sub-path` // or without sub paths if they don't appear in the original url

except when URL contains `xyz`

```
const nextConfig = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/:path((?!xyz).*)',
                destination: `https://www.someurl.abc/:path*`,
                permanent: true
            },
        ]
    },
    i18n: { 
        locales: [...],
        defaultLocale: 'en'
    },
    // more properties
}
```

That works for redirected routes as expected (but not with a locale!), but it doesn't seem to work for `localhost:3000/en/xyz`

- If I use a route that doesn't include xyz, redirect works but locale is not preserved
- With `xyz` in the URL, if I don't specify the locale (`localhost:3000/xyz`) it loads a blank page instead using the default locale
- With `xyz`, With a locale `localhost:3000/en/xyz` it redirects even though I don't want it to

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) instead of redirects. By default, rewrites are applied after checking the filesystem. That means you could create a route file in `pages/xyz` and a rewrite rule like:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        // note: i haven't checked if this is valid, just used the example provided above
        source: '/:path(.*)',
        destination: `https://www.someurl.abc/:path*`,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

This way, all explicitly defined routes such as `/xyz` (as well as their localised routes, e.g. `/eng/xyz`), will be handled by their page components, whereas everything else will be redirected.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "rewrites are applied after checking the filesystem"?

Comment: Also, how does your code exclude  paths including `xyz` specifically? A complete example for "you could create a route file in pages/xyz" would be much appreciated.